# jsonschema2pojo is not creating generated java object

Tags: java, json, maven, hl7-fhir, jsonschema2pojo

I'm trying to use jsonschema2pojo to convert the FHIR schema to a java object. If I use [this example schema](http://%20%20http://json-schema.org/learn/examples/address.schema.json) then the generated java classes are create just fine, but when I use this [Json Schema](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/fhir.schema.json.zip) then nothing is created and I don't see any errors to understand why its not created. Can anybody help me understand where the failure is?

My pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>DMSAdpater</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                <targetPackage>com.example.types</targetPackage>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Output of my mvn compile

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.example:DMSAdpater:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< org.example:DMSAdpater >-----------------------
[INFO] Building DMSAdpater 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ DMSAdpater ---
[INFO] Deleting H:\Workspaces\HDI\Project\DMS_Adapter\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:1.0.2:generate (default) @ DMSAdpater ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ DMSAdpater ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ DMSAdpater ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  25.745 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-13T12:01:07-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As a general rule, I wouldn't try to generate Java code for FHIR from the schema.  You're *much* better off using the HAPI open source Java reference implementation.  (Schema doesn't express many of the rules associated with FHIR and your generated code isn't going to be nearly as clean/capable as an API that's specifically designed to support FHIR.)

Comment: The JSON schema for FHIR is pretty complex because of the resourceType property. That's likely the source of the problem - to do with the way all definitions are dependent